# INCOME TAX ANALYSIS: How to run a loop involving floats(decimals as intervals)

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I am trying to compute the tax analysis (PAYE) using `if` loop ('cos that's what I know), the first and last loop works fine but returns 0 for 2nd, 3rd and 4th loop.

I tried rounding up the input variable and it works but I get wrong decimals which is not accepted.

```
import numpy

#TAXABLE = 200333.33
#TAXABLE = 282645.83
#TAXABLE = 65203.83
#TAXABLE = 133364.58
#TAXABLE = 20495.83
#TAXABLE = 147083.33
#TAXABLE = 10328.83
#TAXABLE = 223908.33
#TAXABLE = 3504.75
#TAXABLE = 890.33
TAXABLE = 119270.83
TAX_INCOME = TAXABLE
#TAX_INCOME = round(TAXABLE)
#TAX_INCOME
TAX=0
#PAYE = 25000
LIMIT1 = 25000
LIMIT2 = 25000
LIMIT3 = 41666.67
LIMIT4 = 41666.67
LIMIT5 = 133333.34


#PERCENTAGE
RATE1=0.07
RATE2=0.11
RATE3=0.15
RATE4=0.19
RATE5=0.21
RATE6=0.24

#CALCULATION
if TAX_INCOME <= 25000:
    TAX1=0
    TAX = TAX_INCOME*RATE1 + TAX1
    if TAX < (0.01*TAXABLE):
        TAX = (0.01*TAXABLE)
if TAX_INCOME in numpy.arange(25001,50001):
    TAX1 = LIMIT1*RATE1
    TAX2 = (TAX_INCOME-25000)*RATE2
    TAX = TAX1 + TAX2
if TAX_INCOME in numpy.arange(50001,91667.67):
    TAX1 = LIMIT1*RATE1
    TAX2 = LIMIT2*RATE2
    TAX3 = (TAX_INCOME-50000)*RATE3
    TAX = TAX1+TAX2+TAX3
if TAX_INCOME in numpy.arange(91667.67, 133334.33):
    TAX1 = LIMIT1*RATE1
    TAX2 = LIMIT2*RATE2
    TAX3 = LIMIT3*RATE3
    TAX4 = (TAX_INCOME-91666.67)*RATE4
    TAX = TAX1+TAX2+TAX3+TAX4
if TAX_INCOME in numpy.arange(133334.34, 266667.68):
    TAX1 = LIMIT1*RATE1
    TAX2 = LIMIT2*RATE2
    TAX3 = LIMIT3*RATE3
    TAX4 = LIMIT4*RATE4
    TAX5 = (TAX_INCOME-133333.34)*RATE5
    TAX = TAX1+TAX2+TAX3+TAX4+TAX5
if TAX_INCOME>=266667.68:
    TAX1 = LIMIT1*RATE1
    TAX2 = LIMIT2*RATE2
    TAX3 = LIMIT3*RATE3
    TAX4 = LIMIT4*RATE4
    TAX5 = LIMIT5*RATE5
    TAX6 = (TAX_INCOME-266666.68)*RATE6
    TAX = TAX1+TAX2+TAX3+TAX4+TAX5+TAX6

#result = format(TAX)
result = "{0:.2f}".format(TAX)
result
```

I expect:

- 65203.83 to return 6780.57;
- 133364.58 to return 18673.23;
- 147083.33 to return 21554.17

but my code keeps returning 0.00.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the problem is in the conditions referring to `numpy.arange`:

```
if TAX_INCOME in numpy.arange(91667.67, 133334.33):
```

requires that `TAX_INCOME` be among a set of values defined as 91667.67 + 1, 91667.67 + 2, ..., 133334.67. I assume your intention would be better expressed as:

```
if 91667.67 < TAX_INCOME  <= 133334.33:
```

If you change all of the conditions in the way above you will get the expected results.

Comment: thank you @sophros, the code now works as should. I appreciate.

Comment: Please sir, can u take a look at the first loop, im trying to return 10% of TAXABLE if the TAX computed is less than 10% of TAXABLE, else it shud return the initial computed TAX...BUT my code is not checking, its just computing the TAX.. CAN YOU ASSIST?????.

Comment: @alhaji - as a token of appreciation could you please mark the answer as correct with the tick mark on the left of the answer and / or upvote it?

Comment: @alhaji: Regarding your second question... are you sure 0.01 is 10%?

Answer (score 0):

numpy.arange will return an array of valued spaced by 1 (unless you specify a different step).

change your if statements like this:

`if TAX_INCOME in numpy.arange(91667.67, 133334.33):`

to

`if TAX_INCOME in >= 91667.67 and TAX_INCOME < 133334.33):`